# Looking for solution to swap position of date format DMY to YMD

Tags: postgresql

I Have some difficulties with my data base.
i have uploaded data from multiple excel file, each file has a spécific date Format. some time DD/MM/YYYY and some time YYYY/MM/DD the column is character varring.
i want to make them YYYY/MM/DD.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution:

```
select regexp_replace('05/01/2019', '(\d\d)/(\d\d)/(\d\d\d\d)', '\3/\2/\1')

 regexp_replace 
----------------
 2019/01/05
(1 row)
```

You could update the table with

```
update my_table
set date_column = regexp_replace(date_column, '(\d\d)/(\d\d)/(\d\d\d\d)', '\3/\2/\1')
```

However, you should basically store dates in a column of type `date.` Use the function to convert differently formatted texts to dates:

```
create or replace function iso_date(text)
returns date language sql immutable as $$
    select case
        when $1 like '__/__/____' then to_date($1, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
        when $1 like '____/__/__' then to_date($1, 'YYYY/MM/DD')
    end
$$
```

The above is an example, you can modify the function if you have more different formats. Now you can alter the column type in this way:

```
alter table my_table alter date_column type date using iso_date(date_column);
```

Read more about [Data Type Formatting Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html) and [POSIX Regular Expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP) in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was very helpful

Comment: I'm glad if this was helpful. Consider accepting the answer to show that the problem is resolved.