# Seperate phone numbers from string in cell - random order

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a bunch of data that contains a phone number and a birthday as well as other data.

```
{1997-06-28,07742367858}

{07791100873,1996-07-14}

{30/01/1997,07974335488}

{1997-04-04,07701003703}

{1996-03-11,07480227283}

{1998-06-20,07713817233}

{1996-09-13,07435148920}

{"21 03 2000",07548542539,1st}

{1996-03-09,07539248008}

{07484642432,1996-03-01}
```

I am trying to extract the phone number from this, however unsure on how to get this out when the data is not always in the same order.

I would expect to one column that return a phone number, the next which returned a birthday then another which return any arbitrary value in the 3rd column slot.

Comment: So you need to extract this in `sql`? And also, please add to your tags in your post what you are using, `sql-server`, `mysql`, etc. Also expected results may help your post as well.

Comment: @RyanWilson - Thanks. I have updated my query.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using. postgre <> sql server. Feel free to add back the tag for the one you are using. Either way I wish you good luck. This is just god awful to parse. No matter what you do you are going to false positives and missed rows.

Comment: I don't know about the exact syntax in Postgres, but you need a regular expression to extract a *series of at least n digits within word boundaries*

Comment: What is the datatype of that column? Are those curly braces stored in the column as well? Please [edit] your question and add the `create table` statement for the table in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to sort parts of each string by the number of digits they contain. This can be done with the expression:

```
select length(regexp_replace('1997-06-28', '\D', '', 'g'))

 length 
--------
      8
(1 row)
```

The query removes curly brackets from strings, splits them by comma, sorts elements by the number of digits and aggregates back to arrays:

```
with my_data(str) as (
values
    ('{1997-06-28,07742367858}'),
    ('{07791100873,1996-07-14}'),
    ('{30/01/1997,07974335488}'),
    ('{1997-04-04,07701003703}'),
    ('{1996-03-11,07480227283}'),
    ('{1998-06-20,07713817233}'),
    ('{1996-09-13,07435148920}'),
    ('{"21 03 2000",07548542539,1st}'),
    ('{1996-03-09,07539248008}'),
    ('{07484642432,1996-03-01}')
)

select id, array_agg(elem order by length(regexp_replace(elem, '\D', '', 'g')) desc)
from (
    select id, trim(unnest(string_to_array(str, ',')), '"') as elem
    from (
        select trim(str, '{}') as str, row_number() over () as id
        from my_data
        ) s
    ) s
group by id
```

Result:

```
 id |           array_agg            
----+--------------------------------
  1 | {07742367858,1997-06-28}
  2 | {07791100873,1996-07-14}
  3 | {07974335488,30/01/1997}
  4 | {07701003703,1997-04-04}
  5 | {07480227283,1996-03-11}
  6 | {07713817233,1998-06-20}
  7 | {07435148920,1996-09-13}
  8 | {07548542539,"21 03 2000",1st}
  9 | {07539248008,1996-03-09}
 10 | {07484642432,1996-03-01}
(10 rows)
```

See also this answer [Looking for solution to swap position of date format DMY to YMD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54062943/1995738) if you want to normalize dates. You should modify the function:

```
create or replace function iso_date(text)
returns date language sql immutable as $$
    select case
        when $1 like '__/__/____' then to_date($1, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
        when $1 like '____/__/__' then to_date($1, 'YYYY/MM/DD')
        when $1 like '____-__-__' then to_date($1, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
        when trim($1, '"') like '__ __ ____' then to_date(trim($1, '"'), 'DD MM YYYY')
    end
$$;
```

and use it:

```
select id, a[1] as phone, iso_date(a[2]) as birthday, a[3] as comment
from (
    select id, array_agg(elem order by length(regexp_replace(elem, '\D', '', 'g')) desc) as a
    from (
        select id, trim(unnest(string_to_array(str, ',')), '"') as elem
        from (
            select trim(str, '{}') as str, row_number() over () as id
            from my_data
            ) s
        ) s
    group by id
    ) s

 id |    phone    |  birthday  | comment 
----+-------------+------------+---------
  1 | 07742367858 | 1997-06-28 | 
  2 | 07791100873 | 1996-07-14 | 
  3 | 07974335488 | 1997-01-30 | 
  4 | 07701003703 | 1997-04-04 | 
  5 | 07480227283 | 1996-03-11 | 
  6 | 07713817233 | 1998-06-20 | 
  7 | 07435148920 | 1996-09-13 | 
  8 | 07548542539 | 2000-03-21 | 1st
  9 | 07539248008 | 1996-03-09 | 
 10 | 07484642432 | 1996-03-01 | 
(10 rows)
```